# Change the form to one that is applicable for that Nexus

Tags: forms, netsuite, moss

I activated the MOSS feature and did the setup.

I use a custom sales order form but when I try to create the Sales order I get the following error :

[image: NetSuite Error]

Which fields or set up I have to apply on the form to be correct

Comment: Have you completed this step: "Assigning a MOSS Nexus to a Company or Subsidiary"?  Reference Suite Answer Id 41001 - https://netsuite.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/41001

Answer (score 0):

You cannot pick a tax code that is not available for the nexus. so if you have a sub with and UK and Ireland Nexus and you are raising a transaction for a customer based in ireland netsuite will push you to use the irish tax codes or get the message error. to bypass it add a tax item(UK) on the customer and it will default to the transaction line.